# PHP Crypt blowfish output and Python crypt differs

Tags: php, python, blowfish, crypt

Have created a hashed password using crypt in PHP and want same hashed out in Python using crypt module. How can I do that?

Here is my PHP Code:

```
function generateSalt($cost = 10) {
    if (!is_numeric($cost) || $cost < 4 || $cost > 31) {
        throw new CException(Yii::t('Cost parameter must be between 4 and 31.'));
    }
    // Get some pseudo-random data from mt_rand().
    $rand = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 8; ++$i) {
        $rand.=pack('S', mt_rand(0, 0xffff));
    }
    // Add the microtime for a little more entropy.
    $rand .= microtime();
    // Mix the bits cryptographically.
    $rand = sha1($rand, true);
    // Form the prefix that specifies hash algorithm type and cost parameter.
    $salt = '$2a$' . str_pad((int) $cost, 2, '0', STR_PAD_RIGHT) . '$';
    // Append the random salt string in the required base64 format.
    $salt .= strtr(substr(base64_encode($rand), 0, 22), array('+' => '.'));
    return $salt;
}

function _hashPassword($password, $salt) {
    return crypt($password, $salt);
}

$salt =  generateSalt();
$pass = _hashPassword('password', $salt);

echo $salt . '<br>'.PHP_EOL;
echo $pass . '<br>'.PHP_EOL;
```

**Output:**

```
$2a$10$Vz1UEa7iImWZ8WN1GVkPtH
$2a$10$Vz1UEa7iImWZ8WN1GVkPt.ZmpAHNOgoR6Xt68WAvT.1TkqaLgeFVu
```

**And tried in Python:**

```
import crypt

def generate_password_salt(cost=10):
    if not isinstance(cost, int) or cost < 4 or cost > 31:
        raise ValueError('Cost parameter must be between 4 and 31.')
    import random, time, hashlib, base64
    rand = ''
    for _ in range(12):
        rand += str(random.choice('ABCDE0123456789'))
    rand += str(time.time())
    sha1 = hashlib.sha1()
    sha1.update(rand)
    rand = sha1.digest()
    return base64.b64encode(rand)[:22].replace('+', '.')

salt = generate_password_salt()
print(salt)

crpt = crypt.crypt('password', '$2$a10$%s$' % salt)
print(crpt)
```

***Getting different output than PHP:***

```
UD8M0q9ufdsr/yqPvgUM2m
None
```

**Now, I want same output in Python as PHP above resulting**

Comment: _"Get some pseudo-random data from mt_rand()"_ does this comment ring a bell? Pseudorandom?

Comment: Please add more details: you hashed a password with PHP and you want to verify it in Python? Or what?

Comment: According to your code you cannot have the same ouput as you generate a random salt in the both cases

Comment: [Python’s *crypt* module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/crypt.html) does only implement the DES-based crypt where the characters in *salt* must be in the set `[./a-zA-Z0-9]`. Since your provided *salt* does not just contain those characters, `None` is returned.

Comment: @Gumbo I tried with `crypt.crypt('password', salt)` and got output "IPWfZkhehzoS2" where salt was "IPXYJQCpy2T7i3UYyp/pmS"

Comment: As I said, Python’s *crypt* module does not implement the Blowfish-based crypt but the DES-based crypt. You need a different module.